# Redirect systemd service STDERR to command (sendmail)

Tags: systemd, io-redirection, stderr, ssmtp

This seems like something that's been asked before but I can't find it anywhere.

I have a systemd service that runs on a timer, updating my packages.  I want to get emailed using `ssmtp` every time the service throws an error.

If I run this in the terminal as root, it works.

```
 # /root/bin/update 2> >(printf "Subject: ERROR from update.service\n\n$(cat -)" | sendmail hostmaster@domain.tld)
Updating package lists... Done!
Updating packages... Done!
Removing old packages... Done!
Cleaning up... Done!
Updating dotfiles... FAILED!
Updating bpytop... Done!
Updating global npm packages... Done!
```

That part that failed sent STDERR which was caught by the pseudo file `>()`.  The `printf "...$(cat -)"` appends a subject to the beginning of the stream.  I get an email with the stderr as body.  Pretty slick, huh?

[image: Screenshot of the email update.service sent]

This is what I want the service to do.  Print the stdout to journald as default, but redirect stderr to a command of my choice.  I tried this first:

```
ExecStart=/root/bin/update 2> >(printf "Subject: ERROR from update.service\n\n$(cat -)" | sendmail hostmaster@domain.tld)
```

But the errors are still sent to journald and not ssmtp.  I think systemd intercepts stderr and sends it wherever is specified by [`StandardError=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardError=).  The `StandardError=` option allows the stderr to be sent to a file descriptor or file... so I tried stuff like this:

```
ExecStart=/root/bin/update
StandardError=file:>(printf "Subject: ERROR from update.service\n\n$(cat -)" | sendmail hostmaster@domain.tld)
```

and

```
StandardError=fd:printf "Subject: ERROR from update.service\n\n$(cat -)" | sendmail hostmaster@domain.tld
```

Didn't work.  It might be possible to send it the StandardError to a named pipe which points to sendmail.  I fooled around with trying to get this to work and finally gave up and came here.

**EDIT**: I also thought about writing a bash function in the update script that sends email, then redirecting stderr from each command in the script to that function.  I'm looking for a solution at the systemd level though, instead of hardcoding the STDERRs' destination in the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with one possible solution: writing stderr to a file and *then* mailing it using `ExecStartPost=`.  I also learned that systemd service files don't play nicely with redirection unless you wrap commands in `/bin/bash -c ''`:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /root/update.err
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/root/bin/update 2>/root/update.err'
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c 'test -f /root/update.err && printf "Subject: ERROR from update.service\n\n$(cat /root/update.err)\n" | sendmail hostmaster@domain.tld'
```

**Source**: [How to pipe Systemd service standard output from ExecStart to shell, ex. bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49227918/3006854)